# Need an override in Firefox & Chrome for line-height: normal !important

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

So i have been spending the better part of this past week stuck on the fact that chrome likes to "minimum-lock" the line-height to match the font on forms. More specifically text, password, and email inputs. Of which I was trying really hard to override.

What I mean by "minimum locking" is that for my font to work on the theme I have made, it has to be 40px. So line-height, for it to look good, is to be set to 28px. But, its being overridden to 41px, i think. Now, I can adjust the line-height above 41px and it will effect the style, but, no less.

I know it works due to the fact that the rest of the site is doing it just fine. I tried a huge array of solutions that apparently work for others found all over Google's searched answers. So after the stress finally conquered me, i decided to just give up and let the extra space go.

**days later**

After finally getting it to look somewhat relevant to the theme I decided to start debugging firefox.

**flips desk ... cries over broken tech ... T.T ... buysNewComputerOpensBoxSetup! ... flips desk again**

Not again! Only this time the submit button is doing the same thing. Except that its "locking" the line height on the button to the font. This completely screws up the flow, and looks odd. **For some of you that might not be a big deal, but, consider me OCD because it needs to work or I scrap it and try all over.**

---

I present to you, the example. Please proceed to the website below, using either firefox or chrome and direct your attention to the login form in the top right. The text and password fields in chrome. And the submit button in firefox.

If your still lost, feel free to edit the Login form css using the inspectors and try doing as i described.

(Edit: Link Removed - Website has changed sense then.)

This image is exactly what I'm looking for. (Keep in mind this was rendered in paint, not in a browser)

[image: This is exactly what im looking for]

---

This image is is what Chrome does to that. This is very much acceptable tho.

[image: chrome happenings]

---

This image is what Firefox does to that. Firefox happens to be doing both problems here. The button is not acceptable.

[image: firefox happenings]

---

Hopefully some well knowledge individuals can shed some light on this issue. ... If not, at least I know where my towel is.

---

**Edit:** Keep in mind its in a factor of 4 all over the theme. So some of the stylings had to be set to odd numbers to fix this. You'll see what i mean when you look at it.

Also, I would like to have a pure CSS/HTML solution. But, will settle for javaScript if none exist.

Comment: Gotta be honest, the line heights look absolutely fine to me - I understand your frustration though. I'll keep looking to try to help but I just wanted to say: I love the aesthetic. It's awesome!

Comment: Oh, uh, let me clarify. Hover your mouse over the top right. Where it says Login. You'll then notice a form with the submit button labeled "Log in". As well as the text and password input fields. and Thanks for the compliment good sir!

Comment: Edited post to reflect this clarification.

Comment: Could you post an image of what it SHOULD look like vs what you're seeing. On Chrome here it looks great.

Comment: hm, ok, give me a couple mins. It'll be up.

Comment: I see your problem in FF. Something bizarre is happening with the submit button there... I'm looking into it now

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to modify the title of your question slightly. It will make it better for people searching in the future. Maybe simplify it to just ask if there is an override to the `line-height: normal` that firefox implements?

Comment: Roger, sounds more precise, changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this:
http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/#.UwdzJfl_soI

From the article:

> Basically, Firefox is setting the line-height to “normal” on buttons
>   and is enforcing this decision with an `!important` declaration.
>
> And while trying to work around this rule, I discovered something that
>   makes the situation a little more dire: browser-defined !important
>   rules cannot be over-ruled by author-defined !important rules. This
>   rule cannot be overruled by a CSS file, an inline style — anything.

Which is definitely related to the problem I'm seeing in Firefox.

The only thing I can think of is creating a div instead to hold the "Login" text and then have a hidden submit button which is triggered on the click event of the button.

That way you get to keep your form all tidy and get the ability to tweak the div till you're happy with it.

EDIT: Here is the jsFiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/F74rf/

Comment: I know about the !important override. _(Said in title, snuck it passed you. :P)_ But, is it possible, about the hidden submit button. I'd absolutely love that. but, I'm hoping its all possible without using javascript, just purely HTML and CSS.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should have read it a little better. The answer will help for anyone stumbling across this question anyhow.
As for only in HTML/CSS... you could do it with very very little JS... I'll put together a JSFiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Added the jsFiddle to the post

Comment: That's easily doable with pure css.

Comment: @nit Could you provide any further information? It's not exactly helpful as-is.

Comment: @Askanison4 Thanks, I'll give it a look over with fresh eyes when i wake up later today. In the mean time, thank you so much for your help.